# plotting function with matplotlib

Tags: python, plotting

I am using anaconda python distribution and I am new here. I need to learn plotting with matplotlib but all the resources I get online including the matplotlib.org pyplot tutorials are not enough to learn how to make function plots etc. Can you suggest me a more beginners to advanced level resource? Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to the site! This site is for *software* recommendations, not learning resource / documentation recommendations. See [our question quality guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/46) for more information. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A really good resource is available on github [here](https://github.com/WeatherGod/AnatomyOfMatplotlib).

It is provided as a set of five tutorials each in an iPython notebook.

- [Part 0: Introduction To NumPy](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/WeatherGod/AnatomyOfMatplotlib/blob/master/AnatomyOfMatplotlib-Part0-Intro2NumPy.ipynb)
- [Part 1: PyPlot](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/WeatherGod/AnatomyOfMatplotlib/blob/master/AnatomyOfMatplotlib-Part1-pyplot.ipynb)
- [Part 2: How To Speak MPL](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/WeatherGod/AnatomyOfMatplotlib/blob/master/AnatomyOfMatplotlib-Part2-HowToSpeakMPL.ipynb)
- [Part 3: Artists](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/WeatherGod/AnatomyOfMatplotlib/blob/master/AnatomyOfMatplotlib-Part3-Artists.ipynb)
- [Part 4: mpl_toolkits](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/WeatherGod/AnatomyOfMatplotlib/blob/master/AnatomyOfMatplotlib-Part4-mpl_toolkits.ipynb)

There is also the recommended book [here](http://www.packtpub.com/matplotlib-python-development/book) and chapters in several other books.